# Making a `REST` call to `graphql` endpoint using apache `httpclient` in java

Tags: java, rest, graphql, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to make a simple rest call to graphql endpoint but getting a `400` error from the server. Have been struck in this for a while.

Payload

```
query = "{\n" +
            "   lookup(dob: \"01/01\", preSsn : { ssn: \"{actualvalue}\"})\n" +
            "   {\n" +
            "       items {\n" +
            "           individualCrdNumber\n" +
            "           firstName\n" +
            "           middleName\n" +
            "           lastName\n" +
            "           suffixName\n" +
            "       }\n" +
            "   }\n" +
            "}";
```

Error message: `{"statusCode":400,"statusDescription":"Bad Request","message":"","messageDetails":[]}`

Code:

```
    HttpClient client = getHttpsClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(query, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpPost.setEntity(input);
    final String plainCred = "userName"+":"+"password";
    final String base64Creds = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainCred.getBytes());


    httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to be wrapped in an object assigned to a `query` element. This object can also contain a `variables` element for value binding:

```
{
  "query": "...",
  "operationName": "...",
  "variables": { "myVariable": "someValue", ... }
}
```

[See the spec regarding GraphQL over HTTP using POST](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request).

Try

```
String query = 
        "{" +
          "\"query\" : \"query {"+ 
            "lookup(dob: \"01/01\", preSsn : { ssn: \"{actualvalue}\"})" +
            "{items{individualCrdNumber firstName middleName lastName suffixName}}" +
          "}" +
        "}";
```

Comment: I tried the option you suggested, and it worked. thanks!